# Cannot invoke 'bindToPort' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use GCDAsyncUdpSocket but I get these errors with bindToPort and beginReceiving functions.

Cannot invoke 'bindToPort' with an argument list of type
'&' used with non-inout argument of type '()'

```
class UDPServer: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {

   let IP = "255.255.255.255"
   let PORT:UInt16 = 2052
   var sock:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

   override init() {
       super.init()
       setupConnection()
   }

   func setupConnection() {
       var err: NSError?
       sock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
       sock.bindToPort(PORT, error: &err)
       sock.beginReceiving(&err)
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I used the try/catch block and another signature. This may changed in a newer version of CocoaAsyncSocket

```
func setupConnection(){
        udpSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

        do {
            try udpSocket.bindToPort(PORT)
            try udpSocket.beginReceiving()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            err.description
        }
    }
```